# Google Analytics Custom Javascript Variable report

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I'm using the Custom JavaScript variable to get the value of "User Name" and "User Email" via Google Tag Manager.

[image]

My question is, how do I create a custom report that shows all the User Email and User Name that accessed my site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that it is against Google Analytics Terms of Service to be collecting anything (name, email, address, phone, etc.) that can be used to personally identify any individual. So I hope you are not pushing that info into GA.

Secondly, generally speaking, you can push information into custom dimensions that can then be used in your GA reports (standard reports, custom reports, etc.). So if you are able to get data into a Custom JS variable, then there should be away for your to push them into a custom dimension.

Please make sure you are complying with the first point.